# Understanding Regex

Tags: java, regex

Hi I know that the character `*` is used to match the preceding character zero or more times, here is the problem, what does zero time in here mean. example: `script[\s]*` if this is the case how does it work, will it block script alone or it'll block script followed by white space.

Answer (score 2):

The `*`, `+`, and `?` modifiers are applied to the expressions immediately preceding them, so in this case the asterisk is applied to `[\s]` alone. If you would like to apply it to `script[\s]`, you can put parentheses around the entire expression: `(script[\s])*`. If you would like to prevent making a capturing group, use `(?:)`, like this:

```
(?:script[\s])*
```

Answer (score 0):

See it [in action](http://regexr.com?31u0g) at Regexr.com.

Some notes:

- You don't need to wrap `\s` with `[]`: `script\s*`
- `\s` means any whitespace.
- I suggest to read [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and try [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/). (or at least [Regexr](http://Regexr.com))

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets mean a character class, `\s` means "space character" (i.e. , `\t`, etc.). So here `*` will be applied to `[\s]` expression, and whole regex means "match `script` followed by zero or more space characters".

Answer (score 0):

The regex you`ve showed will work like:

1) Match the characters 'script' literally

2) Match a single character that is 'whitespace character'(spaces, line breaks, etc)

2.1) As many times as possible

So it will match the single 'script' as well as 'script_***_***'(any number of spaces)

Answer (score 0):

> what does zero time in here mean?

The same as it means somewhere else.

For instance, "I poked you zero times" means that I didn't poke you at all.

Or "I poked you zero or more times" means I didn't poke you, or I poked you once, or twice or ...

> example: script[\s]* if this is the case how does it work, will it block script alone or it'll block script followed by white space.

The regex will *match* `"script"` or `"script "` or `"script  "` and so on.